# AngularJS Render Raw JSON from Play Framework backend

Tags: angularjs, nginx, playframework, reverse-proxy

I have a simple AngularJS application that is supposed to call a URL and render the resulting JSON as is. Here is the index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Hello AngularJS</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        function Hello($scope, $http) {
            $http.get('http://localhost:9000/status').
            success(function(data) {
                $scope.greeting = data;
            });
        }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div ng-controller="Hello">

            <pre>{{greeting | json}}</pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The url when I call as is from the browser, I get the JSON that I expect, but I see a blank page when I call localhost:8080

I then tried to call a different URL from a completely different server:

```
http://rest-service.guides.spring.io/greeting
```

And this renders the content as expected:

```
{"id":1,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

I'm running the index.html inside NGINX server, while my backend server running on port 9000 is served by Play framework. Here is my NGINX configuration:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  localhost;
    root /Users/joesan/Projects/Sandbox/my-app;

    #charset koi8-r;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
            # If you want to enable html5Mode(true) in your angularjs app for pretty URL
            # then all request for your angularJS app will be through index.html
            try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # /api will server your proxied API that is running on same machine different port
    # or another machine. So you can protect your API endpoint not get hit by public directly
    location /api {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. I had to enable CORS filter on my Play application. I'm using Play framework 2.5 and here is the reference document from Play on how to configure CORS filter:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CorsFilter

Additionally, in the application.conf, I had to do the following:

```
  cors {
    # Filter paths by a whitelist of path prefixes
    pathPrefixes = ["/"]

    # The allowed origins. If null, all origins are allowed.
    allowedOrigins = null

    # The allowed HTTP methods. If null, all methods are allowed
    allowedHttpMethods = ["GET", "POST"]
  }
```

Comment: Here is the complete setup if in case someone is looking for a project template: https://github.com/joesan/nginx-mac-os-setup